React Native Expo: Error - Duplicate resources during mergeReleaseResources
When im going to create eas build --platform android
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.


[drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_userimg] /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_userimg.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_userimg] /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_userimg.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources


Try:


Run with --stacktrace
option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 6m 35s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
In react native expo project structure i don't have android folder

These are my file with no android folder
enter image description here
I'm not get proper solution on it.
